# Use jniRegisterNativeMethods to register methods instead of long JNI names in Android Studio with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-ndk, jnienv

Is there any way to use `jniRegisterNativeMethods` to map JNI functions in a NDK app? *i.e.* use a `method_table` to map native (C/C++) functions *via* the JNI instead of using ridiculously long JNI method names?

For example, in one exercise I saw, there was a C file added onto the platform it self,

```
#include "core_jni_helpers.h"
#include "jni.h"

static jlong init_native(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz)
{
    return 0;
}

// ...

static JNINativeMethod method_table[] = {
    { "init_native",     "()J",  (void*)init_native     },
    { "finalize_native", "(J)V", (void*)finalize_native },
    // ...
};

int register_android_server_ExampleService(JNIEnv *env)
{
    return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env, "com/android/server/OpersysService",
            method_table, NELEM(method_table));
};
```

But then the `register_android_server_ExampleService` was was manually invoked in `services/core/jni/onload.cpp` (on the platform)

Is there any way to do this or something similar with the NDK though?

My guess is no, as `JNIHelp.h` and `core_jni_helpers.h` aren't available in the NDK, and the Kotlin tools in Android Studio likely wouldn't be able to run a function in order to perform the auto complete.  However I thought it was worth asking in the small case I could somehow avoid naming functions like `Java_vendor_<name>_<name>_<name>_test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI`

Comment: Note that `RegisterNatives` is part of the JNI (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html), so you can implement the equivalent of `jniRegisterNativeMethods` yourself. As for Android Studio being able to detect your methods and allow things like "Go to definition", I have no idea.

Comment: I had a colleague tell me after I wrote this (I haven't been able to test it yet): > Call `jniRegisterNativeMethods` from `JNI_OnLoad`.  The JVM will look a `JNI_OnLoad` function and call it if it exists.  I found an [example: SimpleJNI/jni/native.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SimpleJNI/jni/native.cpp)